# switch navigator in react-navigation v5

Tags: react-native, navigation, react-native-navigation, react-navigation-v5

There is a good example of switch navigator in V4 documentation of react-navigation:

https://snack.expo.io/@react-navigation/auth-flow-v3

I didn't understand how can I change this into a proper way for V5. here is the link:

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/upgrading-from-4.x.html#switch-navigator

Any assistance you can provide would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Well, if you want to implement a "switch" like feature with V5, you need to opt into using the new `<Stack.Navigator />` definition. Basically, the `<Stack.Navigator />` can have children which are `<Stack.Screen />` and anytime you explicitly switch between them (or set them to null), it will animate between them. You can find more documentation on how to do this here: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/auth-flow

Answer (score 2):

There is no `createSwitchNavigator` in React-Navigation v5.
So it can be implement as below.

App.js

```
// login flow
const Auth = createStackNavigator();
const AuthStack =()=> (
    <Auth.Navigator 
        initialRouteName="Login"
        screenOptions={{
          animationEnabled: false
        }}
        headerMode='none'
    >
        <Auth.Screen name="Login" component={LoginScreen} /> 
        <Auth.Screen name="Signup" component={SignupScreen} />
    </Auth.Navigator>
 )

// drawer use only in authenticated screens
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();
const DrawerStack = () => (
        <Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
            <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
            <Drawer.Screen name="Settings" component={SettingsScreen} />
            <Drawer.Screen name="Logout" component={LogoutScreen}/>
        </Drawer.Navigator>
)
const RootStack = createStackNavigator();

 class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      loading: true,
      hasToken: false,
    };
  }
 
 componentDidMount(){
    AsyncStorage.getItem('jwtToken').then((token) => {
      this.setState({ hasToken: token !== null,loading:false})
    })
  }

  render() {
    const {loading,hasToken} = this.state;
    
    if (loading) {
      return <WelcomeScreen/>
    } 
   else  {
      return( 
          <NavigationContainer>
              <RootStack.Navigator headerMode="none">
           { !hasToken ? 
              <RootStack.Screen name='Auth' component={AuthStack}/>
           : 
              <RootStack.Screen name='App' component={DrawerStack}/>
           }
           </RootStack.Navigator>
          </NavigationContainer>  
      );
    }
  }
}
export default App;
```

This is only one way of doing authentication.I haven't use Redux or React Hooks here.You can see the example which used React Hooks in the React Navigation v5 documentation.

Answer (score 2):

I think I found a solution for this issue which will block all unwanted navigation from the user and still keep smooth transitions between screens.

1. You need to add **navigation.service.js** like this:

```js
import * as React from 'react';

export const navigationRef = React.createRef();

export const navigate = (routeName, params) => {
  navigationRef.current?.navigate(routeName, params);
}

export const changeStack = (stackName) => {
  resetRoot(stackName)
}

const resetRoot = (routeName) => {
  navigationRef.current?.resetRoot({
    index: 0,
    routes: [{ name: routeName }],
  });
}
```

2. add that **ref** from **navigationService** to **NavigationContainer** like this:

```js
<NavigationContainer ref={navigationService.navigationRef}>
  <Navigation />
</NavigationContainer>
```

now when you know you need to change stack, just call **changeStack** instead of **navigate**.

I have explained this solution in more details here:
[Change stacks in react-navigation v5](https://dev.to/bigtoni/change-stacks-in-react-navigation-v5-1g4j)